# Supermicro 5037MC-H8TRF network wont link up with 100Mbps switch

Tags: networking, supermicro

We have a Supermicro 5037MC-H8TRF micro cloud rack with 8 servers. Each has 2 1Gbps NIC. It works fine with a 1000Mbps switch. But when I connect it to a 100Mbps switch, it does not work(It won't link up). Is there any fix for this? I have only one 1000Mbps switch. I'm planning to do an openstack install for which I'm planning to use the 1Gbps switch for data network and 100Mbps switch for management network.

Edit: I checked the product page here [http://www.supermicro.com/pr..](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/3u/5037/sys-5037mc-h8trf.cfm). It says the NIC supports 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX, and 1000BASE-T, RJ45 output

Switches Used:
100Mbps Switch: Linksys SR224.
1000Mbps Switch : Linksys SR2024.

Comment: What "it does not work" means? The NIC doesn't up or It up but can not to communication?

Comment: It does not up.

Comment: What switch do you use?

Comment: 100Mbps Switch : Linksys SR224.
1000Mbps Switch : Linksys SR2024.

Comment: Make sure you have enable all port in your switch, and check if your switch port is config port-security.

Comment: The SR224 switch is unmanaged. So I believe there is no configuration options? Also, the switch works fine with my laptop.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the Gigabit ethernet port, and not the IPMI port (there are three total, 2 GB, 1 IPMI).

Comment: Yes, IPMI is found separately right? And the 2 GbE ports are together. I'm connecting to one of them.

Comment: Is this after you've installed an O/S? Can you configure the port to be 100BASE-TX full duplex manually?

Comment: This is before installing the OS. I don't know how to do that. Is it done in the OS or in BIOS?

Comment: I'm actually not too sure, some NICs nowadays have BIOS prompts, it might be worth seeing if there is something accessible via the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definately in the BIOS.

What o/s are you running on this?

I have found that using the 'auto negotiate' option for port speed doesnt work
reliably with some chipsets.  More specifically...i've found over the years that
the higher the price of the switch or router, the less capable it is to auto negotiate
with an off brand from itself.  i.e. cisco to a dell switch...auto negotiate port speed is
horrible.  cisco to cisco works fine.

In your case, however, i'd guess its the o/s driver that needs to be checked.